# 0.01 differecene in django calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding, django-1.9

The below-described issue occurred on Python3 with Django 1.9.4

In my Django project, to calculate discount on the sale_amount I am using the below line of code

```
discount = round((sale_amount - tax_amount ) * discount_rate,2)
```

the values for the above variables are as follows

```
sale_amount,tax_amount, discount_rate = 30.00, 6.75, 0.02000000
```

Variable values are fetched from Django model object all are of same type i.e decimal.Decimal

The calculated discount in a Django project file based the above lines of code is `0.46`

When I am calculating discount using the above-described amounts and formula I am getting `value: 0.47` in Django console

I am not able to figure out why there is a `0.01` difference between Django console and project calculation.

Comment: you sure? round() in python function, irrespective of Django version, I am getting 0.47 in python3

Comment: Yes, I am sure,  I am getting the same result as you are getting (correct values i.e 0.47) in the python console and Django console, but I am getting the wrong value(0.46) in the Django web application.

Comment: Please share the code base with templates if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of (30 - 6.75) * 0.02 is 0.465. So we would expect to get 0.47 when rounding. But here seems to be an explanation : [round() documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round).

> The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you suggest a solution to my problem.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were only looking for an explanation as to why did this happen. In the documentation I linked in my answer, they suggest using [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal). I can't tell you much more ; your question picked my interest but I have no real Python or Django knowledge.